# phpStorm doesn't recognise xDebug debugger

Tags: installation, phpstorm, xdebug

I have MAMP Pro 3, have xDebug installed and activated (if I go to the xdebug.org and analyze the php info I see it’s installed)

Still MAMP Pro doesn't recognize the debug information. (see screen)

Any idea what can it be?

[image]

phpinfo() - https://www.diigo.com/item/image/4qykm/4qso

Comment: Proofs please. Output of `phpinfo()`

Comment: I have added a snapshot of the phpinfo()

Answer (score 1):

1. Your `phpinfo()` was captured via browser (served by Apache) ... while PHP Interpreters in PhpStorm is a CLI thingy (i.e. to be executed in terminal). On some systems/setup (mainly Linux & Mac) they use different settings (different php.ini files).
2. You clearly have **two different** `php.ini` files used in both cases. For PHP Interpreters you have to edit that file that you have on your screenshot with PHP Interpreters (just click on `Open in Editor` link next to it).

   - Your Apache uses `/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf/php.ini`
   - PHP Interpreters one uses `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/conf/php.ini`

   You have to edit the last one and enable/configure xdebug there.

**Keep in mind** that PHP Interpreters will only be used if you execute/debug CLI scripts or other PHP-powered tools (like PHPUnit tests/CodeSniffer/PHPMD integration/Composer/Phing etc). If you **only** want to debug files served by Apache .. then PHP Interpreter is not required (and you can ignore what it says there).

**P.S.**
It's also possible that you may have more than one PHP installation on your computer (even if they are both the same version) -- double check that.